# How do I create a layer like this with leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

## This is what I want to create

https://i.gyazo.com/126add227f5d0756c407fb84fe12b3eb.mp4

You see the colored layer over the map.   I first thought it was the heat map feature, but the color regions are sharp whereas heat map color regions more like are gradient.

I checked the network tab, and something like this is possibly the data building the colored layer.  I only numbers, like 2000 points depending on the window size (bigger the more).
[image]

I believe it's a some kind of layers, and I looked through examples, but none of them are like the one I want.

Does anybody know what this layer is called in leaflet?

Comment: maybe you can use a polygon?

Comment: I also thought that could be, but their colored layer is so much in details, I don't know if putting many polygons with that much in details is what they are doing.

Comment: see: [Leaflet: Heatmap plugins](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#heatmaps) eg: [Leaflet.heat](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/demo/). You can set the `radius` and `blur` parameters to make starker boundaries.

Comment: then maybe you could have some sort of image overlay?

Comment: @pilchard I believe it's not a heat map layer.

Comment: @knosmos ooohh I guess you are right.  I checked the network tab for images, and there are images just like the layer.  I think they are using some sort of image tiles.

Comment: Hard to say with so little information, but could also be done probably with a UTF Grid combined with canvas rendering.

Comment: @ghybs I checked network tab, and I see images are being loaded.  And the urls are in this format (/zoom/x/y.png).  https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames   So now I believe it's just image tile layer.